# MySqlHelper not pushing through query parameters to MySQL

Tags: mysql, .net

I have a WPF/.Net 4.5 C# app, and I'm using MySQL NET Connector 6.8.3. I'm trying to execute a stored proc in a MySQL database, that expects 3 parameters.

The table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `geofences` (
  `id_geofences` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `shape_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_geofences`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_geofences_UNIQUE` (`id_geofences`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name_UNIQUE` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The stored proc is as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_geofence`(geofenceName VARCHAR(45), geofenceDescription VARCHAR(255), typeId INT, shapeId INT)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO geofences (`name`, `description`, `type_id`, `shape_id`) VALUES (@geofenceName, @geofenceDescription, @typeId, @shapeId);
END
```

This is my C# code:

```
string sql = "call insert_geofence (@geofenceName, @geofenceDescription, @typeId, @shapeId);";
MySqlParameter[] parameters = new MySqlParameter[4];
parameters[0] = new MySqlParameter("@geofenceName", "test name");
parameters[1] = new MySqlParameter("@geofenceDescription", "test description");
parameters[2] = new MySqlParameter("@typeId", 1);
parameters[3] = new MySqlParameter("@shapeId", 2);

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(ConnectionString, sql, parameters);
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
"Column 'name' cannot be null"
```

I have made column `name` a NOT NULL column. So it appears the values of the parameters are not being sent through to the stored procedure. Indeed, if I remove the NOT NULL restriction from the `name` column, the query executes, but all four columns are NULL.

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. Any ideas? Thanks...

Comment: Not able to test now, so I don't post this as an answer, but I think you should use `MySqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(connstring, "call storedProc1(name, surname, age)", parameters);` Let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks Steve. I tried that, but then I get this error:
    "Unknown column 'name' in 'field list'"

I also tried this:
    call storedProc1(@name, @surname, @age)", parameters);
i.e. putting the @ in front of the parameters, but then it gives me the same error again:
    "Column 'name' cannot be null"

:/

Comment: Can I ask you why you need to use MySqlHelper class instead of a regular MySqlCommand?. And looking back to my example it seems that I have missed the semicolon at the end of the string (`call storeProc1(name, surname, age);"`

Comment: Tried with the semicolon, no luck. Ive always used MySqlCommand, but I wanted to try MySqlHelper for a change for 2 reasons: 1. I read on MySQL's site that MySqlHelper is now the recommended/preferred techonoly to use, and 2. I have the feeling connection pooling doesn't work well using standard MySqlConnection and MySqlCommand - if I open and close a connection repeatedly, instead of keeping the connection open behind the scenes to improve performance, I've noticed it was actually opening and closing the connection each time. I wanted to see if connection pooling worked better on MySqlHelper

Comment: What I find amazing is that I can't find one example of MySqlHelper being used (with parameters) in a .Net language anywhere on the net!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried a similar code to yours and it works as expected after some little changes

First the SP is like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_test`(n varchar(10), f varchar(255))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO filename (username, file) VALUES (n, f);
END
```

Now the call to the SP is like this

```
string conn = "Server=localhost;Database=test;Uid=root;Pwd=root;Port=3306";
string cmdText = "call sp_test(@n, @f);";
MySqlParameter[] parameters = new MySqlParameter[2];
parameters[0] = new MySqlParameter("@n", "steve");
parameters[1] = new MySqlParameter("@f", @"d:\temp\test.txt");
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(conn, cmdText, parameters);
```

It is important that you use the same name without the prefix for the parameters' name and for the placeholders in the Sql Statement. Instead it seems that the `@ prefix` is required in the C# code

Comment: It seems that your SP defines the parameters without the `@` prefix but then tries to use them with the `@` prefix. Done the same at my code above and get your error `username cannot be null`. Remove the `@` prefix in the sql INSERT statement

Comment: Thanks Steve - let me tell you I tried every conceivable combination of the @ prefix - in the insert query, in the call method, in the parameters array.... eventually the right combination was, as you suggested, not to have the @ prefix in the CREATE PROCEDURE, but to have it in both the calling query, and the parameters array :)